# What is the rate of bacterial cell death due to viruses on land?

Tags: bacteriology, ecology, virology

> "The rate of viral infection in the oceans stands at 1 × 10^23 infections per second, and these infections remove 20–40% of all bacterial cells each day." - https://www.nature.com/articles/nrmicro2644

What are the equivalent figures on land?

Comment: "On land" is pretty vague in this context. Are you just interested soil? Would you include surface waters? Wetlands? Animal-associated microbiomes? I think it's a simpler calculation for oceans, as marine biomass is largely dominated by microorganisms, whereas terrestrial biomass is dominated by plant life.

Comment: True, it is vague. I'd be interested in figures for any non-ocean ecosystems. Animal and soil microbiomes in particular.